# Icons for Drop-down Menu and Sidebar Minimizer no longer seen

Tags: html, css

So I'm not the most familiar with HTML, but I know enough to make very minor tweaks.

I had this issue all of a sudden where I updated my github page website, and a few icons were  missing.

Sidebar toggle(top right of pic) and sub-menu dropdown chevrons:

[image: sidebar]

Envelope icons next to email addresses:

[image: email]

The little icons for the sidebar minimizer, dropdown menu, and the "envelope" icons used to represent emails disappeared.

I redownloaded the template I built my website on just to check if I did something wrong: https://html5up.net/editorial

But even in the newly downloaded file, those icons were missing, whereas when I first downloaded them, they weren't

Given that this issue also happened in a freshly downloaded template (but as you see on the website preview the icons are fine), I'm baffled as to what the issue might be.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

The icons missing are F0C9, F078 and F0E0.

Comment: How are the icons being referenced in CSS? They should be like: content: ‘\f0c9;’.

Comment: heya. I double checked the css a few times, and it definitely looks right: https://i.gyazo.com/6566edd517fb90dd4ede0e1a67b8b23a.png Moreover i didn't so much as touch any of the css files (mostly i was just editing images and tweaking html code in notepad++)

Comment: Those icons are set with FontAwesome characters. You see those boxes when the font doesn't load correctly. Are you hosting the fonts on your site, or getting them from another host? They could be getting blocked by your server or browser.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that helped with my understanding of it! I'm now getting them from another online host, that seemed to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to put the FontAwesome CDN in the main.css file, change:

```css
@import url(fontawesome-all.min.css);
```

For this:

```css
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css);
```

Remember that the file all.css (FontAwesome) depends on several online fonts